# Un Json que no me funciona

Tags: php

Disculparme, pero parece que tengo un dia espeso.
Tengo un programa que me devuelve un json con la lista de ficheros; podeis verlo aqui:

```
http://gestionproyectos.com/?controller=Salida&modelo=00&action=pedirListaProgramas
```

Pero cuando intento hacer el decode...

****Antes de realizar ninguna salida, un buen **ob_clean()** hace que todo vaya mejor....Esta incidencia queda resuelta así.

```
$directorio =file_get_contents($ruta . 'action=pedirListaProgramas');
$lista=json_decode($directorio[0]);
echo "directorio[0]---------------------------------------\n";
var_dump($directorio);
echo "lista---------------------------------------\n";
var_dump($lista);
echo "fin---------------------------------------\n";
```

no lo consigo, os muestro los var_dump

```
directorio[0]---------------------------------------
string(233) "["MODELO.ini","RutinasInicio.php","actualizaVersion.php","configHostName.php","configWiFiSer.php","descargarFichero.php","detectUsb.php","imagenes.js","index.php","inicializacion.php","inicio.php","inicio.sh","version-actual.php"]"
lista---------------------------------------
NULL
fin---------------------------------------
```

la rutina que genera el json es:

```
 public function pedirListaProgramas($request){
    $protegidos=['opciones.ini','*MODELO.ini','datos'];
    $ruta=$this->rutaVersion($request);

    $todos=scanDirectories($ruta,false);
    $lista=array_diff($todos,$protegidos);
    $json = json_encode($lista);
    echo "todos------------<br>\n";
    var_dump($todos);
    echo "lista------------<br>\n";
    var_dump($lista);
    echo "json------------<br>\n";
    var_dump($json);
    echo "Fin------------<br>\n";
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $json;
    exit();
}
```

y sale:

```
    todos------------<br>
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "MODELO.ini"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "RutinasInicio.php"
  [2]=>
  string(20) "actualizaVersion.php"
  [3]=>...

    lista------------<br>
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "MODELO.ini"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "RutinasInicio.php"
  [2]=>
  string(20) "actualizaVersion.php"
  [3]=>...

    json------------<br>
string(230) "["MODELO.ini","RutinasInicio.php","actualizaVersion.php","configHostName.php","
```

¿Que estoy haciendo MALLLLLL!
Tras probar este cambio, el resultado sigue saliendo mal
El nuevo fragmento, queda asi:

```
$directorio =file_get_contents($ruta . 'action=pedirListaProgramas');
echo "directorio[0]---------------------------------------\n";
var_dump($directorio);
$lista=$directorio[0];
echo "lista---------------------------------------\n";
var_dump($lista);
echo "fin---------------------------------------\n";
```

pero el resultado sigue siendo

```
directorio[0]---------------------------------------
string(233) "["MODELO.ini","RutinasInicio.php","actualizaVersion.php","configHostName.php","configWiFiSer.php","descargarFichero.php","detectUsb.php","imagenes.js","index.php","inicializacion.php","inicio.php","inicio.sh","version-actual.php"]"
lista---------------------------------------
string(1) "▒"
fin---------------------------------------
```

Comment: Haz json_decode($directorio) en lugar de json_decode($directorio[0]), y una vez decodificado el json ya recorres los elementos.

Comment: Coincido con @Carmen , según los `var_dump` mostrados debes hacer uso de `json_decode($directorio)`.

Comment: Si hago `json_decode($directorio)` me da NULL

Comment: @migarcia editaste la respuesta que te coloqué, debes editar tu pregunta con los nuevos detalle. Saludos!.

Comment: El problema es que la URL `http://gestionproyectos.com/?controller=Salida&modelo=00&action=pedirListaProgramas` no te devuelve ni un JSON, ni un array. Eso es una cadena sin más. Si eres el programador de esa página debes modificar la URL para que te devuelva los datos como los necesitas: JSON o array...; o debes contactar al programador para que modifique el tipo de respuesta; o conformarte con manipular el dato para convertirlo a JSON o a array, quitándole los símbolos `[]"` y haciendo un `explode` con la coma como separador. Algo precario ciertamente lo cual no te recomiendo.

Comment: Fijate que he compartido la rutina que se supone genera el JSON....

Comment: Ok, no había visto que compartiste `pedirListaProgramas`. ¿Puedes editar la pregunta poniendo un `var_dump` de cada dato que manejas en esa función? Haces varias llamadas a otros métodos y aplicas funciones como  `array_diff` por lo que no podemos ver lo que eso estaría produciendo, hay que mirarlo con lupa, dato por dato.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta modificanto la función que retorna el json, comentanos a ver

Comment: @zerocool, Tras la modificacion sigue apareciendo correcto el json, pero al recibirlo (con file_get_content), su decode me da NULL. Te  lo digo asi, porque no se donde seguir editando

Comment: Solo necesito tener un array con la lista de los archivos que hay en una carpeta del servidor!!!!

Comment: vamos al chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89569/un-json-que-no-me-funciona

Comment: @zerocool no consigo escribir nada en el chat

Comment: volvi a editar la respuesta con el caso que hice para probar tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes mal es el JSON en sí, eso no es un JSON ya que el objeto json se compone de clave:valor:

```
{nombre:"jose"}
```

En tu caso tienes:

```
["MODELO.ini","RutinasInicio.php","actualizaVersion.php","configHostName.php","configWiFiSer.php","descargarFichero.php","detectUsb.php","imagenes.js","index.php","inicializacion.php","inicio.php","inicio.sh","version-actual.php"]
```

Si puedes moficar el servicio que te retorna los datos entonces debes hacer que retorne:

```
{"ficheros": ["MODELO.ini","RutinasInicio.php","actualizaVersion.php","configHostName.php","configWiFiSer.php","descargarFichero.php","detectUsb.php","imagenes.js","index.php","inicializacion.php","inicio.php","inicio.sh","version-actual.php"]}
```

De lo contrario procésalo directamante sin hacer el decode ya que php debería ver que es una array, intenta hacer primero:

```
var_dump($directorio);
```

Antes de hacer el decode.

EDITO:

Viendo que puedes modificar el servicio puedes hacer que retorne un json válido:

```
public function pedirListaProgramas($request){
$protegidos=['opciones.ini','*MODELO.ini','datos'];
$ruta=$this->rutaVersion($request);

$todos=scanDirectories($ruta,false);
$ficheros=array_diff($todos,$protegidos);
$json = json_encode(compact('ficheros',$ficheros));

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
exit();
}
```

Fijate que cambio el nombre de la variable lista por $ficheros, además modifico la variable $json para que almacene el resultado de codificar a json lo que retorna la función compact, que es crear un objeto a partir de una variable existente, de allí que cambie la variable lista a "ficheros" nada más para que tenga sentido en el json retornado. Te dejo un link a compact: [compact php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.compact.php)

EDITO 2:
Dejo la prueba que hice en mi local:

Archivo json.php tiene el código (un poco modificado para que me funcione) de tu función pedirListaProgramas

```
<?php

$todos = ["MODELO.ini","RutinasInicio.php","actualizaVersion.php","configHostName.php","configWiFiSer.php","descargarFichero.php","detectUsb.php","imagenes.js","index.php","inicializacion.php","inicio.php","inicio.sh","version-actual.php"];
$protegidos=['opciones.ini','*MODELO.ini','datos'];

$ficheros=array_diff($todos,$protegidos);
$json = json_encode(compact('ficheros',$ficheros));

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
exit();
?>
```

Ahora el archivo que lo procesa:

```
<?php 
$ruta = "http://localhost:8000/json.php";
$directorio =file_get_contents($ruta);

$datos = json_decode($directorio);
var_dump($datos->ficheros);

foreach($datos->ficheros as $fichero)
   echo $fichero."<br>";

?>
```

Acá se aplica el json_decode a la variable $directorio que tiene la respuesta de la petición con el json, luego hago var_dump a la propiedad "ficheros" (recuerda que cambiamos la funcion "pedirListaProgramas" para que retorne un json valido {"clave":valor}), por ende el var_dump queda de esa manera y te coloco además cómo podrías procesar cada elemento del arrray "ficheros" con un foreach.

Nota: coloca tus nuevas dudas de éstos puntos en los comentarios de este respuesta.

Saludos.

Comment: Lo he probado; funciona perfectamente....hasta que a tu programa de proceso, le pongo la ruta de mi programa ´$ruta='http://gestionproyectos.com/?controller=Salida&modelo=00&action=pedirListaProgramas';`
Al parecer, mi programa genera tres bytes mas, que no puedo ver pero que provocan un error
`string(243) "{"ficheros":["MODELO.ini","RutinasInicio.php","actualizaVersion.php","configHostName.php","configWiFiSer.php",...","version-actual.php"]}"`  

`string(246) "{"ficheros":["MODELO.ini","RutinasInicio.php","actualizaVersion.php","configHostName.php","configWi..."]}"`

Comment: El programa que genera el JSON en el servidor, me esta añadiendo tres ascii que son el 239, el 187 y el 191. Si recorto la string retirando esos tres caracteres, funcionan....
Si sabeis como los estoy generando, os agradecería que me deis pistas....

Comment: si, estoy viendo a ver que pasa, puede ser la función que escanea el directorio, como estas haciendo eso

Comment: En la línea del json enconde si imprimes eso ya tienes los caracteres extras?: $json = json_encode(compact('ficheros',$ficheros));  o es cuando se hace el encode? o cuando se retorna?, qué framework usas?

Comment: Cuando genero el JSON (despues de encode) esta en 243, por lo que no me ha añadido nada. 
En este proyecto, no llegue a utilizar ningun framework, aunque respete el modelo MVC

Comment: YA ESTA.....parece que hay rastros en el buffer de response. Antes de empezar a preparar la respuesta, hago un ob_clean() .....y funcionando....

Comment: Pues bueno :D si te ayudó ésta respuesta márcala como aceptada ;D

Comment: Te puedo dar las gracias, porque mi reputacion es muy baja....

Comment: No importa la reputación, acá te comentan cómo es: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers saludos que bueno que resolviste